# mapbubble does not work with highcharter highmaps

Tags: r, dictionary, highcharts, geojson, r-highcharter

I would like to create a bubble map with highcharter. For this I have my own map, the corresponding coordinates (Colleges) and the quantity (students).

The coordinates are displayed correctly as points (mappoint), but as soon as I want to display the proportions (mapbubble), no more points are displayed. Probably this is related to the hs_geojson file.

What can I do so that the points are displayed according to their size?

```
colleges.csv
name       lat          lon         z
College 1  5701710.310  375630.091  11.523
college 2  5401410.358  345730.591  25.586
```

```
# data 

  data <- read.csv2("colleges.csv")

  data_geojson <- geojson_json(data,lat = "lat", lon = "lon")
  class(data_geojson)
 
# map

  map <- ("map_geojson.geojson") %>%
    fromJSON(simplifyVector = FALSE) %>%
    as.json()

  # mapbubble

  map <- highchart(type = "map") %>%
    hc_add_series(mapData = map, showInLegend = FALSE)
  map
  
  map %>%
    hc_add_series(
      data =   data_gjson,
      name = "Colleges",
      type = "mapbubble",
      minSize = "1",
      maxSize = "10%"
    )%>%
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = TRUE)
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution ?