# How to create a "mapbubble" map with {highcharter) with example?

Tags: r, highcharts, geojson

Maybe it's duplicated with [mapbubble does not work with highcharter highmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66567770/mapbubble-does-not-work-with-highcharter-highmaps) but there was no answer to the question...

From the example taken at https://jkunst.com/highcharter/articles/maps.html with a map of type "mappoint", I try to achieve the same with "mapbubble". I created for this a column z

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(geojsonio)
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

ausgeojson <- GET("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries/AUS.geo.json") %>%
  content() %>%
  fromJSON(simplifyVector = FALSE) %>%
  as.json()

ausmap <- highchart(type = "map") %>%
  hc_add_series(mapData = ausgeojson, showInLegend = FALSE)
ausmap

airports <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajdapretnar/datasets/master/data/global_airports.csv")
airports <- airports %>% 
  filter(country == "Australia", name != "Roma Street Railway Station") 
airports <- airports %>% 
  mutate(z=runif(n=nrow(airports),min=1,max=20))

airp_geojson <- geojson_json(airports, lat = "latitude", lon = "longitude")

# works with mappoint
ausmap %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = airp_geojson,
    type = "mappoint",
    dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
    name = "Airports",
    tooltip = list(pointFormat = "{point.name}")
  )

# doesn't work with mapbubble
ausmap %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = airp_geojson,
    type = "mapbubble",
    value = "z",
    dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
    name = "Airports",
    tooltip = list(pointFormat = "{point.name}")
  )
```

Comment: Maybe I need to add `z` column to my Geojson file `airp_geojson` ?

Comment: `jsonlite` can red direct from a url - `ausgeojson <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries/AUS.geo.json", simplifyVector = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably due to the fact that {highcharter} cannot access the other columns of the geojson file.
Example if I add another column to the `tooltip` argument in the `mappoint` case :

```
ausmap %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = airp_geojson,
    type = "mappoint",
    dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
    name = "Airports",
    tooltip = list(pointFormat = "{point.name} : {point.altitude}")
  )
```

I don't see altitude :
[image]